# remove outliers based on median and standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('fi.xlsx')
f=df.loc[df['Description'].isin(["F32T8/SPX41/ECO2"])].sort_values(['TimeStamp'])
```

//fi file

```
,Name,Price,Brand,Description,Sheet,TimeStamp,Date
83,"Fluorescent Linear Lamp, T8, Cool, 4100K",$8.10,GE LIGHTING,F32T8/SPX41/ECO2,Tradional,1399352872,2014-05-06 08:07:52
86,T8 Starcoat® Ecolux® 4 ft.,$187.56,GE Lighting,F32T8/SPX41/ECO2,Tradional,1451072074,2015-12-25 21:34:34
81,"68852-Ecolux® Starcoat® Fluorescent Lamp, T8, G13 Base, 48 in., 32W, 4100K",$6.43,GE Lighting,F32T8/SPX41/ECO2,Tradional,1582483587,2020-02-23 20:46:27
82,F32T8/XL/SPX41/ECO2,$4.92,General Electric,F32T8/SPX41/ECO2,Tradional,1582483587,2020-02-23 20:46:27
84,"Fluorescent Linear Lamp, T8, Cool, 4100K",$1.75,GE LIGHTING,F32T8/SPX41/ECO2,Tradional,1582483587,2020-02-23 20:46:27
85,GE 68852 F32T8/SPX41/ECO2 - T8,$2.00,GE,F32T8/SPX41/ECO2,Tradional,1582483587,2020-02-23 20:46:27
```

What I am trying to do is remove outliers in this case it would be the $187

```
f.replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'[\$]',value=r'')
f['Price'] = f['Price'].astype(float)
median = f['Price'].median()
stdev= f['Price'].std() #74.7177102611333 doesn't make sense because of outlier
```

What is a "Good" way to remove such outliers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tukey's fences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) is an easy and simple way to deal with outliers. It uses quantiles Q1 (percentile 25) and Q3 (percentile 75) to create value limits:

[image]

where k is a positive constant. Following Wikipedia links and Tukey's references,

> k=1.5 indicates an "outlier", and k=3 indicates data that is "far out".

I would use one of these 2 values for your k.

In that link you can also find more information about other methods.

Comment: I assume you mean like this `q = df["Price"].quantile(0.02)`  I got the follow error `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: anyway according to the function a valid range would be (-368.75,564.5)

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of ways:

```
outlier = 187.56

# simply filter out the outlier
df = df.query("Price < @outlier")

# another way to cap it at some xth percentile
df['Price'] = np.where(df['Price'] >= outlier, df['Price'].quantile(0.9), df['Price'])
```

Comment: This makes sense since I "manually" gave it the outlier, is there a more automated way based on median or std ?